# upload file with php doesn't work

Tags: php, upload

hi everyone i have a form html, i want upload file with this form

```
<body>
    <div align="center">ELENCA TABELLE PRESENTI NEL DB</div>
        <form action="index.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Filename:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="/include/js/bootstrap-contextmenu.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/include/js/bootflat.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/s/bs/pdfmake-0.1.18,dt-1.10.10,af-2.1.0,b-1.1.0,b-colvis-1.1.0,b-html5-1.1.0,b-print-1.1.0,cr-1.3.0,fc-3.2.0,fh-3.1.0,kt-2.1.0,r-2.0.0,rr-1.1.0,sc-1.4.0,se-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

i have this script php for upload a file with this form, i want upload a file into my uploads root

```
$UploadDirectory    = 'uploads/'; //Upload Directory, ends with slash & make sure folder exist
$SuccessRedirect    = 'successo.html'; //Redirect to a URL after success


if (!@file_exists($UploadDirectory)) {
    //destination folder does not exist
    die("Make sure Upload directory exist!");
}

if($_POST)
{
    if(!isset($_POST['mName']) || strlen($_POST['mName'])<1)
    {
        //required variables are empty
        die("Title is empty!");
    }


    if($_FILES['mFile']['error'])
    {
        //File upload error encountered
        die(upload_errors($_FILES['mFile']['error']));
    }

    $FileName           = strtolower($_FILES['mFile']['name']); //uploaded file name
    $FileTitle          = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mName']); // file title
    $ImageExt           = substr($FileName, strrpos($FileName, '.')); //file extension
    $FileType           = $_FILES['mFile']['type']; //file type
    $FileSize           = $_FILES['mFile']["size"]; //file size
    $RandNumber         = rand(0, 9999999999); //Random number to make each filename unique.
    $uploaded_date      = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    switch(strtolower($FileType))
    {
        //allowed file types
        case 'image/png': //png file
        case 'image/gif': //gif file
        case 'image/jpeg': //jpeg file
        case 'application/pdf': //PDF file
        case 'application/msword': //ms word file
        case 'application/vnd.ms-excel': //ms excel file
        case 'application/x-zip-compressed': //zip file
        case 'text/plain': //text file
        case 'text/html': //html file
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
    }


    //File Title will be used as new File name
    $NewFileName = preg_replace(array('/s/', '/.[.]+/', '/[^w_.-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), strtolower($FileTitle));
    $NewFileName = $NewFileName.'_'.$RandNumber.$ImageExt;
   //Rename and save uploded file to destination folder.
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mFile']["tmp_name"], $UploadDirectory . $NewFileName ))
   {
        header('Location: '.$SuccessRedirect); //redirect user after success

   }else{
        die('error uploading File!');
   }
}

//function outputs upload error messages, http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#90522
function upload_errors($err_code) {
    switch ($err_code) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
            return 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
            return 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
            return 'No file was uploaded';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
            return 'Missing a temporary folder';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
            return 'Failed to write file to disk';
        case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
            return 'File upload stopped by extension';
        default:
            return 'Unknown upload error';
    }
}
```

but the result's ever is "title is empty" with all types of file, why? i searching over the web but nothing..

Comment: What is mName? there is no such field as mName in your form?

Comment: @Federico Castellani, is there any field in the name of mName, if so then please check my answer and if not so then please let us know what is that field.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_POST['mName']) || strlen($_POST['mName'])<1)
```

You are looking for `$_POST["mName"]` but there is no field with the `name` attribute of "mName" in your form, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="mName">
```

---

Similarly:

```
if($_FILES['mFile']['error'])
```

Here you look for a file with name "mFile", but the `input` in your form has the `name` attribute value of "file".

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
 if(!isset($_POST['mName']) || strlen($_POST['mName'])<1)
```

with

`if(!isset($_POST['file']) || strlen($_POST['file'])<1)`

Answer (score 0):

Since the values that you are using to check is not assigned, you need to assign them. Here are the changes that you need to do in your form :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Filename:
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="file" name="mFile" id="mFile">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="mName" id="mName">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```